# Acquiring statistics in ONOS

Tags: sdn, openflow, onos

I found several ways to get statistics from ONOS, DeviceService, FlowStatisticService, MeterService and StatisticService. But what I want to do is acquiring a statistic of specific one flow traveling many links. Those methods doesn't provide flow-level specific statistics. For example, DeviceService provides port-level statistics. And StatisticService provides list of flow entries which don't contain flow ID. So what I want to do is

1. I want to get statistic of each flow with flow ID to identify whether it is same flow of other links.
2. I want to limit bandwidth of those flow

Is there similar provided methods in ONOS? otherwise do I have to develop?

Answer (score 0):

For getting `statistic` of each flow, you can use the `REST` `API` to get statistics for a specific `DeviceID` and a given `FlowID`. For example, you can use:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 
    'http://<controller_ip>:8181/onos/v1/flows/{deviceId}/{flowId}
```

Replace `{deviceId}` and `{flowId}` with your desired Ids.